# Form validation numeric range (minimum/maximum) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Have a script that defines text as being a number using a regular expression:

```
function validateTextNumericInRange(textInputId)
{
    var numRegex = /^[\d]+$/;
    var textInput = document.getElementById(textInputId);

    var valid = true;
    if (numRegex.test(textInput.value) == false) {
        alert('Value must be a number between 3-48');
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Need to use this format and provide a min/max range (arbitrary for now, say between 3 and 48). How would I modify this regex to complete and have a correct argument?

Comment: integer and decimal numbers or just integers?

Answer (score 12):

I don't understand your question. Do you mean that you want a number that is between 3 and 48 digits, or that the value of the number must be between 3 and 48?

For the latter you don't need a regex:

```
function validateTextNumericInRange (textInputId) {
    var textInput = document.getElementById(textInputId);
    var value = parseInt(textInput.value, 10);

    return (!isNaN(value) && value >= 3 && value <= 48);
}
```

A more generic solution:

```
function validateTextNumericInRange(textInputId, min, max) {
    var textInput = document.getElementById(textInputId);
    var value = parseInt(textInput.value, 10);

    return (!isNaN(value) && value >= min && value <= max);
}
```

To test to see if a number is between 3 and 48 digits long, you can use the regular expression `/^[0-9]{3, 48}$/`.

Comment: Dont forget to add the radix for your parseInt call

Comment: Going for a number between 3 and 48.  Just convinced my "superiors" not to use regex for this task.  Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Your superiors wanted to use regex for this? O_o

Comment: They had some Json rules written around regex but I managed to talk them out of it.  Your solution worked just fine and they were comfortable once I demonstrated and explained it to them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

A regular expression would be hard and inflexible, and for your example it would be:

```
/^(?:[3-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8])$/
```

Better go with Vivins' solution.

Comment: Imagine you have a string which contains a week of year number and you want to check it in early stages, before conversion to integer. My case! Thanks: `^(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|[5][0-3])$`

Answer (score 3):

```
function isInteger(value) {
  if ((value.toString()).replace(/^-\d|\d/, "").length == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function integerInRange(value, min, max) {
  if (isInteger(value)) {
    if (parseInt(value, 10) >= min && parseInt(value, 10 <= max)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false; // Not in range
    }
  } else {
    return false; // Not an integer
  }
}

integerInRange( 55,  3, 48); // Returns false
integerInRange("55", 3, 48); // Returns false

integerInRange( 25,  3, 48); // Returns true
integerInRange("25", 3, 48); // Returns true
```

In your case you would need to call it this way:

```
integerInRange(document.getElementById(textInputId).value, 3, 48);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a good JavaScript developer, but I know that in Java you can use this syntax to test for minimum and maximum length:

```
[1-9][0-9]{2,4}
[1-9][0-9]{min,max}
```